# How to build a rosbuild package from source

Tags: ros, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find a good guide to do this. I have cloned the source using 'bzr branch', what are the next steps?
The package I am trying to use is [sick_ldmrs](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_ldmrs).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247424/how-to-build-a-rosbuild-package-from-source/) by [danzda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28455/danzda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you are probably on a recent ROS version, you will need to convert the package to the catkin build system. The [catkin migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) should contain all the relevant information. The [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/) will also be useful.

edit: Whoops, my bad, I was just attended to the fact that you *can* actually use rosmake to build ros packages for the more recent distributions. Have a look at the [rosbuild wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild) and [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/Tutorials) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-07**:
Whether this specific package will build successfully on anything newer than Electric is of course also dependent on the way it interacts with its dependencies. If the code has bitrotted too much, `rosbuild` or `catkin` will just be one of the issues to fix.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-07**:
Additionally: migrating the package to Catkin would probably be a good idea in any case. Do make sure there isn't a catkinised version somewhere (on Github fi) already.

**Comment by [danzda](https://answers.ros.org/users/28455/danzda/) on 2016-11-07**:
Thank you for the help, got it working now.